# VLC SDR 10 Bit 4k video stuttering in Ubuntu 16.04 on ThinkPad P52 with NVidia Quadro P1000

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, vlc

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 installed on my ThinkPad P52.

Hardware configuration is - 
Processor: i7 8750H (6 cores, 12 threads)
RAM: 16 GB 2400 MHz
NVME Drive: Samsung NvME EVO Plus 500GB
GPU: NVidia Quadro P1000 (Mobile)

[image]

I believe hardware configuration is more than enough to play 4k SDR videos with 10 bit encoding.

When I play SDR 4k 10 bit video using VLC 3 on Windows 10, it works perfectly smooth. But, when I play the same SDR 4k 10 bit video using VLC (both VLC 3 and VLC 4) on Ubuntu 16.04, it continuously stutters. 

 
 NVidia Graphics Driver on Ubuntu is already installed which is available in official repository. The version is 384.

[image]

Anybody know what's the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Increased the thread count in Preferences->all->Input/Codecs->Video Codecs->FFmpeg->Decoding->Threads. I increased it to 100. After that playback is smooth.

[image]